# Fused lasso for image denonising

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization, image-processing, signal-processing

For a given data $y_{i}$, with $i=1, \dots, n$, we consider the following signal approximation:
$$
\hat{y} = \arg \min_{w}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-w_{i})^{2} + \lambda \sum_{(i,j)\in E}|w_{i} - w_{j}|,
$$
where $E$ is the set of edges corresponding to the two-dimensional grid.

The question: for image denoising what are the typical metrics and the typical way to choose $\lambda$ parameter?

Comment: i like to use the eyeball norm: for your first ten images, compute reconstructions at a logarithmic grid of $\lambda$ values and see which looks best.

Comment: That's an intriguing typo in the title ;-).